# ffmpeg gets slow after a while

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rendering

I have installed ffmpeg on my win r2 server and it gives me headache with rendering videos!
When i have installed ffmpeg and have started to render videos (700MB mp4 video into 3 clips of 7:00 minutes mp4 videos) it worked pretty good, an 700MB video was rendered in 3 clips in 10 minutes!

After rendering 30-40 videos in clips it started to slow down, now 1 clip takes 10-20 minutes!

I have rebooted my machine but it does not change anything, it renders a clip in 10-20 minutes instead of 3-4 minutes!

I have reinstalled OS and installed ffmpeg again and it works great, it does the rendering in 3-4 minutes but after a couple of videos it slows down again to 10-20 minutes per clip!
Do you have simillar experience or any suggestions how to avoid the slowdown?

My server details are :

6GB RAM
4 Cores
500GB HDD
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard OS

Comment: Sounds a lot like disk fragmentation to me.

Comment: ok,i have fragmented my disc and it was not the reason!

Comment: @ LordNeckbeard - i will deliver the command line tomorrow!